# A Good way to draw technical Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I'm currently writing a research paper. For that I need to create some diagrams like the one given below(it is taken from an existing paper). It's not clear so I wanted to make my own figure. I tried using tikz to create the figure. But I didn't understand how to include the curly braces part. I can include the text as a process type or an ellipse type node. But How should i include the curly braces ? Are there any other tools that simplify this process.

[image: Image created using Multiple jpegs.]

Comment: In this particular case you can include curly braces inside a nose with math content. Your diagram will consist in graphic nodes and text nodes one over the other.

Comment: For braces with TikZ, look at the `decorations.pathreplacing` library for a generic solution, or in this case you can use a `matrix`, so look at the `matrix` library which allows you to add delimiters to a `matrix`.  Might be easier to do as Ignasi suggests though, and do the braces in math mode.

Comment: @Ignasi How can put two nodes on top of each other ?

Comment: @naiveBayes [rpapa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308013/1952), already showed what I was proposing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the solution to adapt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=2em, minimum width=8em](pred) {(1) Prediction};
\node[below=0em of pred](equa1) {
$\left\{\begin{aligned}
A_t&= F A_{t-1}\\
P_t&=F P_{t-1}
\end{aligned}\right.
$};
\node[below left=9em and 5em, draw,minimum height=2em, minimum width=8em](update){(2) Update(filter)};
\node[below=0em of update](equa2) {
$\left\{\begin{aligned}
A_t&= F A_{t-1}\\
P_t&=F P_{t-1}\\
K_t&=K_{t-1}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
$};

\node[below right=9em and 5em, draw,minimum height=2em, minimum width=8em](done){(2) (2) Do nothing};


\draw[->](equa1.south) |- ++(-1em, -1em) -- node[left]{data is existing}(update);
\draw[->](equa1.south) |- ++(1em, -1em) -- node[right]{data is missing}(done);


 \draw[->] (done.east) --++(2em,0) |- (pred);
 \draw[->] (equa2.west) --++(-2em,0) |- (pred);

\node[below=15em of pred,draw,minimum height=2em, minimum width=8em] (filter){(3) Filter};

 \draw[->] ($(pred)+(0,-8em)$) -- (filter); 
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]